# Getting the message "Your version of github for mac is too old" on Github web site

Tags: github

I'm trying to download a file from Github but the "Open" button is grayed out and a tooltip says "Your version of github for mac is too old to open this file. Try checking for updates." But I'm not using Github for Mac! I'm using the web site through Google Chrome! Is it not possible to open files from the web site?

Comment: github can only go off what your browser is telling it. maybe you set chrome to masquerade as a mac?

Comment: It shouldn't matter whether I'm running Mac, Windows, Linux, Solaris, BSD, or OS/2. Github for Mac is a software program and it's not what I'm using, and I would find it rather discouraging if it was really just a shell to the Github web site which Github for some reason thinks I'm inside.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out this is just bad user interface design, or perhaps deceptive user interface design. What I actually wanted to do was the "Raw" button. The "Open" button tries to open the file with a desktop program, in this case Github for Mac because that's my operating system.

Guess all I can do is complain about a bad interface and hope that others who are confused will find out that the "Open" button does not do what it claims; for that you want the "Raw" button.

Comment: The new Github Desktop gave me a similar [ad] page. I had  clicked to add my enterprise account, and got the 'too old' error. Google did not help in that the github.com canonical reference for the error redirects to [the ad]. Sigh. ty @meustrus!